deployment error in my nexjs application with Prisma orm
during the deployment of my application on Vercel, at the construction stage, I receive the error shown in the attached image.
I've also associated the package.json file.
{
  "name": "house_for_rent",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/prisma-adapter": "^2.4.1",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.1.4",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.6.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.16.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-hover-card": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-menubar": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-switch": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-toast": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@vercel/postgres": "^0.9.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "embla-carousel-react": "^8.1.6",
    "lucide-react": "^0.395.0",
    "next": "14.2.4",
    "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.19",
    "next-themes": "^0.3.0",
    "prisma": "^5.16.2",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.52.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.2.1",
    "resend": "^3.4.0",
    "sonner": "^1.5.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "use-debounce": "^10.0.1",
    "usehooks-ts": "^3.1.0",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "zod": "^3.23.8",
    "zustand": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


I was hoping my deployment would be a success and I got this errorsdeployment errors obtained on Vercel
